# How to detect change on the screen?

Tags: c#

I have a question that How to detect the change on the screen? Its position is not necessary but is possible to get its position it will be helpful. I searched it on the internet but not found any suitable answer. Now, I am making a program in C# and I have to detect a change on the screen. I tried to capture four screen shots per second and compare them. This method works but it badly effect on the performance of the PC.

I think it is easy to do in C or Assembly language (x86) because in assembly we can get access to video memory directly.

Is it possible to do in C#?

Code sample will be appreciated.

**Project:** *Detect any change on full Screen camera monitoring software.*

Comment: I'm pretty sure accessing video memory isn't quite as easy as it once was now that more sophisticated graphics cards are common.

Comment: May i ask what are you trying to accomplish? Making a program that reacts to every single change on the screen (even just a single pixel) doesn't seem correct. You may have different routes to accomplish your task

Comment: Are you looking some kind of motion detection codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really looking just for simple difference of what you see on your monitor? I doubt that would do the job.
For motion detection from cam input you can take a look at [Motion Detection Algorithms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Motion_Detection.aspx) article on CodeProject.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from taking screen captures and comparing them at some time intervals (which would cause performance issues),
The only solution i can think of is hooking up to system events, the "redraw" kind of events.

You will need to choose which events to hook your program with.

This codeproject tutorial might help-
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WilsonSystemGlobalHooks.aspx